# How do I get checkbox "on" using Python Flask without causing a 400 bad request error?

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I've got a form which is submitting a post request to Flask.  It all works perfectly except when a checkbox is not ticked which causes a 400 error unless I have a try: except: catch for each option.

The challenge is that I have a lot of checkboxes and it seems like there would be a better way than just having a dozen try: except: checks.

Is there a more Pythonic way of doing this please?

Currently the HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="control">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input name="option_1" type="checkbox">
     Option 1
    </label>
</div>
```

My Python code looks like:

```
try:
    print(request.form['option_1'])

except:
    print("option_1 not selected")
```

Comment: Can you maybe provide a minimal working example of your Python and HTML code so it's possible to reproduce?

Comment: No need - it's already been answered perfectly.  Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a key might not exist, use `.get(...)` instead of accessing it directly, for example:

```
print(request.form.get('option_1'))
```

Comment: Thanks Janos - I've accepted and added in my own example.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Janos for the explanation, whoop only prints if the box is ticked with no error if it's not there.

```
if request.form.get('option_1'):
        print('whoop')
```